# Frequency Counter Input Impedance

Tags: rf, input-impedance, frequency-measurement

I have been looking at RF frequency counters  and noticed that they all have one port that says up to 50 MHz with an input impedance of 1 megaohm. However the +50 MHz input says 50 Ohm impedance.

If the one input is 1 megaohm how does that work when measuring a HF signal at 50 Ohms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RF has signal integrity issues at 1 MOhm above 50 MHz due to resonance. The low impedance dampens the ringing from inductance and self capacitance of cable or reflections from longer cables from impedance mismatches.

Scope probes have similar issues, that can be improved by removing the inductive ground clip and probe tip and only using the coaxial tip and ring.

Naturally RF signal integrity relies on a low source impedance as well. <=5 V CMOS logic does have low source impedance and in the case of 3.3V logic with 3.6Vmax, it can be too low such as 25 ohms so in cases of long coax adding 25 ohms or more improves damping factor by matching the source to the cable to meter with 50 ohms. At this point , logic levels are unimportant from this reduction for freq. measurements.